# Is it possible to install Jitsi meet on my existing EC2 instance?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

I have decided to install jitsi meet on AWS.  I have an an elastic beanstalk site with [ Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux ] platform.
The EC2 instance is t2.micro, but in production I will have up to 110 users having conferences every day with a maximum of 3 conferences taking place at any given time.
The best guide I could find on how to proceed with the installation on AWS is [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/getting-started-with-jitsi-an-open-source-web-conferencing-solution/)
But obviously I would have to make a new instance to do that.  The big difference is that the instructions need ubuntu to be installed on the instance, and I don't have that on my current instance.  I am not so familiar with linux, is it possible to translate those instructions meant for Ubuntu into my current instance, so I don't have to pay for a new instance?

Comment: Did you read the article first? "Jitsi needs a fair bit of memory, so using the micro instances will not work without tuning/hacking, which is outside the scope of this article."

Comment: The problem I foresee, is that if I simply upgrade the instance (using a tutorial like, https://www.cloudsqueeze.ai/how-to-change-an-aws-ec2-instance-type-a-step-by-step-guide/index.html), then I won't be able to SSH into the instance and run the commands that are required by the link in my question, which requires Ubuntu.

Comment: I found a possible solution using the aws cli, using the command:
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --solution-stack-name "Ubuntu ..." --environment-name "dev-bg-123456" --region "eu-central-1"
but I'm afraid that changing the platform of elastic beanstalk is going to break my site.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new step by step video tutorial on setting up Jitsi on AWS https://youtu.be/Oq1vPZdYNNA

Comment: Hello, link-only answers tend to not age well as links rot and videos get taken down. Please include at lease a summary of what is at the URL so this answer can stand alone.